# How do I set the parent state before rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

*I know this is a really long introduction, but I really struggle to make myself clear here*

In this `Next.js` application that I'm working on, I need to set a CSS grid layout on a `div` that has a certain `id`. I do this with styled-components `createGlobalStyle`. I want every child of this App component to be able to change this grid layout ( optionally pass in alternative CSS values ).

I have set the default grid CSS values in the state ( fallback, in case the function wasn't called by a child ). I created a class method ( `setLayout` ) that can set the layout state with a received argument. I pass a reference to this function to every child component with a React Context.

In my child component, I can now import this context and call the function with an alternative layout. It works. But... when I refresh the page first the fallback layout blinks for just a second before the child component layout gets applied to the root div.

In other words, on first render the App component is rendered with the fallback values, then the child component is rendered with calls a function which changes the state of the App component, which triggers a re-render. Then on second render, the App component is rendered with the correct layout.

 
*I really want the App component to render the child-provided layout (if it is provided ) on first render without first rendering the fallback.* Please help me achieve this.

P.S. I'm using server-side-rendering, although I don't think this has any effect

```
// App component
// I have trimmed a lot of non relevant logic 
export const LayoutSetter = createContext((layout: Layout): void => {});

export default class App  {
  constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      layout: {
        columns: "100vw",
        rows: "50px 50px",
        areas: "
         header 
         content
        ",
      },
    };
  }

  setLayout(layout: Layout): void {
    this.setState({ layout: layout });
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    const __NextStyle = createGlobalStyle`
      #__next {
        display: grid;

        grid-template-columns: ${this.state.layout.columns};
        grid-template-rows: ${this.state.layout.rows};
        grid-template-areas: "${this.state.layout.areas}";
      }
    `;

    const setter = (layout: Layout): void => this.setLayout(layout);

    return (
      <>
        <__NextStyle />
        <LayoutSetter.Provider value={setter}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </LayoutSetter.Provider>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Child component
const layout: Layout = {
  columns: "90vw",
  rows: "50px 500px",
  areas: `
    header
    section
  `,
};

const Home = (): JSX.Element => {
  const setLayout = useContext(LayoutSetter);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLayout(layout);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that since the child is a product of the `App` render it doesn't get hot until after `App` renders it. By then `App` has already rendered and with the default layout.

1. `App` renders (with default)
2. Part of `App` render triggers render of `Child`
3. In `Child`, `setLayout` is executed
4. `App` layout is updated.

Unfortunately what you're trying to achieve (at least the way you're trying to achieve it) cannot be done. What you can do alternatively is have no default layout until `setLayout` is called. Essentially don't render a specific layout until `setLayout` is called in the child. Then, in `setLayout` you can do something like below.

```
  setLayout(layout: Layout): void {
   if (layout){
     this.setState({ layout: layout });
   } else {
     this.setState({ 
        layout: {
           columns: "100vw",
           rows: "50px 50px",
           areas: "
             header 
             content
           ",
        } 
     });
   }
  }
```

Initial state could be

```
layout: {
    columns: "",
    rows: "",
    areas: "
      header 
      content
    ",
},
...
```

But then you run into other styling issues (like having no layout might look bad). You could compensate for this with setting your `NextStyle` component's opacity at `0` until `this.state.layout.columns.length > 0`.

```
var opacity = this.state.layout.columns.length > 0 ? 1 : 0;

const __NextStyle = createGlobalStyle`
      #__next {
        display: grid;
        opacity: ${opacity};
        grid-template-columns: ${this.state.layout.columns};
        grid-template-rows: ${this.state.layout.rows};
        grid-template-areas: "${this.state.layout.areas}";
      }
    `;
```

This way you're at least not showing anything until `setLayout` is called. I'm not sure if you'd prefer that to the little blink of default layout you described but it might be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll go and try it out!